# How to calculate the duration between two dates in same column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to calculate the Break Duration of user(Break Duration=Unlock-Lock Time).

Can anyone please tell me how to calculate that.

below is my table

```
Event id  EventDate                       EventType            Userid
1     2015-11-05 13:54:28.900       Login                10
2     2015-11-05 13:55:27.527       Lock                 10
3     2015-11-05 13:55:27.537       Break                10
4     2015-11-05 13:55:37.037       Unlock               10
5     2015-11-05 13:56:13.953       Break                10
7     2015-11-05 14:33:26.347       Login                10
8     2015-11-05 14:33:46.243       TaskStartedInManual  10
9     2015-11-05 14:34:34.570       TaskPause            10
```

My break formula is not always same. In the below example my Break Event is in between Login-Taskpause.So basically whenever there is a break in EventType calculate Previous row of Date-Next row of date.How can i achieve that?

```
EventId  EventDate                EventType   Userid
1   2015-11-05 13:54:28.900   Login        10
2   2015-11-05 13:55:27.527   Lock         10
3   2015-11-05 13:55:27.537   Break        10
4   2015-11-05 13:55:37.037   Unlock       10
5   2015-11-05 14:33:26.347   Login        10
6   2015-11-05 14:33:46.243   Break        10
7   2015-11-05 14:34:34.570   TaskPause    10
```

Desired Output will be

```
Userid  Break_Duration(In sec)
10         10
10         68
```

Comment: can you post your desire output?

Comment: can you explain why is 68, I dont see what value produce that.

Comment: The value 68 comes from the date difference Login-TaskPause for e.g select DATEDIFF(s,'2015-11-05 14:33:26.347','2015-11-05 14:34:34.570')

Comment: I still dont understand your logic. You never mention Login Task pause on your description.

Comment: Thanks for your time.Basically i want to calculate the Break Duration for the event type Break so whenever there is a 'Break' in between two event type i want to calculate the date difference of previous event type-Next event type.let me know if you still have any question?

Comment: Yes, I need a visual example. Update your question and explain with an example

Answer (score 2):

Asign an `ID` to each event type and then match by that `ID` to calculate [**DATEDIFF**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a3a47/8)

```
with cte as (
      SELECT s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by [EventType] order by [EventDate]) as rn
      FROM shift s
)
SELECT L.[Userid], DATEDIFF ( second, L.[EventDate], U.[EventDate] ) as breaktime_seconds
FROM cte U  -- unlock
JOIN cte L  -- lock
  ON U.rn = L.rn
 AND U.[Userid] = L.[Userid]
WHERE U.[EventType] = 'Unlock'
  AND L.[EventType] = 'Lock'
ORDER BY L.[Userid]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| Userid | breaktime_seconds |
|--------|-------------------|
|     10 |                10 |
```

Comment: My break formula is not always same. In the below example my Break Event is in between
Login-Taskpause.So basically whenever there is a break in EventType calculate Previous row of Date-Next  row of date.How can i achieve that?
EventId  EventDate                EventType   Userid

1 2015-11-05 13:54:28.900   Login        10
2 2015-11-05 13:55:27.527   Lock         10
3 2015-11-05 13:55:27.537   Break        10
4 2015-11-05 13:55:37.037   Unlock       10
5 2015-11-05 14:33:26.347   Login        10
6 2015-11-05 14:33:46.243   Break        10
7 2015-11-05 14:34:34.570   TaskPause    10

Comment: Put the example in your question not as comment.

Comment: Thanks.Added the example in question

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `DATEDIFF` function to do this:

`DATEDIFF('d', [COLUMN1], [COLUMN2])`  where `d` is the type of difference you want (days in this example)

See the MSDN [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) page for full details.